# 355/113 and small odd cubes

Tags: pi, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

An important approximation to $\pi$ is given by the convergent $\frac{355}{113}$.

The numerator and the denominator of this fraction are at the same distance of small consecutive odd cubes.

$$\frac{355}{113} = \frac{7^3+12}{5^3-12}$$

[image: 133 and 355 match]

> Is this a consequence of some general formula, such as a series or continued
> fraction?

---

**Attempts, drafts**

$$\frac{113}{355} = \frac{1}{10}\left(2+\frac{5^3}{3+\frac{7^3}{4}}\right)-\frac{8}{355} = \frac{1}{5}\left(3-\frac{5^3}{3+\frac{7^3}{4}}\right)$$

Similarly, for $\frac{22}{7}$

$$\frac{7}{22} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3^3}{1+\frac{4^3}{2}}\right) -\frac{1}{11}$$

For the first convergent $3$,
$$\frac{3^3-6}{1^3+6}=\frac{21}{7}=3$$

The tentative expression
$$a(n)=\frac{(4n+3)^3+6(3n-1)}{(4n+1)^3-6(3n-1)}$$

has $a(0)=3$ and $a(1)=\frac{355}{113}$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a(n) = 1 \neq \pi$

A similar fraction for the approximation $\frac{223}{71}$ (Archimedes' lower bound) is
$$\frac{98+5^3}{98-3^3}=\frac{2·7^2+5^3}{2·7^2-3^3}=\frac{223}{71}=3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{10}}$$

Comment: If so would $22/7$ be expressible that way also, being an earlier convergent to the (simple) continued fraction for $\pi$ ?

Comment: Not sure how to reach $\frac{22}{7}$, but $\frac{25-3}{4+3}$ would suggest squares instead of cubes. From cubes, $\frac{22}{7}=\frac{3^3-5}{2^3-1}$, not that nice.

Comment: Jaume-- Good one using squares! [I was trying that but fouled it up.]

Comment: We have $\frac{4^3 + 2}{3^3 - 6}$, still different.

Comment: FWIW, here's a little live Sage / [Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwli0EKAjEMAO99RdhTAyKy3gr6FVlrIkFM15h6Kf271Z3rzGSGE-SiLlrpdmFbskvRuAqG1UQ9ZsbAxUB24CAKpPVJtjgNsx_nh-xO6u-ImAIMto2nJmnuCdrIXrW4jCgKpmOH5n3CfysMAmeYD9v642q0PL4RFi83&lang=sage) to show partial quotients & convergents of $\pi$.

Comment: $$3=\frac{2^3+4}{2^3-4}$$

Comment: When a partial quotient is 1, we get convergents that are neighbours in a [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours_and_continued_fractions) eg, $22/7, 355/113, 333/106$, with $355 = 22 + 333$ and $113 = 7 + 106$. That can give us linear patterns, but of course it doesn't explain squares & cubes.

Comment: I've found a couple via the convergents of $\sqrt[3]\pi$: $$\frac{517^3+13607}{353^3-13607} = \frac{22}{7}$$ and $$\frac{41^3+10}{28^3-10} = \frac{333}{106}$$

Comment: Did you try diff/sum as well?

Comment: I solved for $x$ in $(u^3+x)/(v^3-x) = p/q$, where $p/q$ is a $\pi$ convergent & $u/v$ is a $\sqrt[3]\pi$ convergent. I just did a brute-force search, looking for combinations that result in an integer value for $x$.

Comment: @coffeemath If it comes from a continued fraction, I think that fraction may also truncate to $\frac{22}{7}$, but not necessarily.

Comment: Maybe this has nothing to deal with $\pi$? Maybe such a representation exists for any rational number, independently on convergent and other stuff?

Comment: Maybe, @Crostul. However, this one is quite simple, $\frac{(n+1)^3+2n}{(n-1)^3-2n}$ for $n=6$. The other examples above are more complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a coprime pair of integers $1 \le p,q$, consider the following diophantine equation:
$$\frac{x^3+z}{y^3-z}= \frac{p}{q}$$
with $x,y,z$ integer unknowns. This is equivalent to
$$z= \frac{y^3p-x^3q}{p+q}$$
Thus a solution exists if and only if there exist $x,y$ such that
$$y^3p-x^3q \equiv 0 \pmod{(p+q)}$$
Now, note that $-q \equiv p$, and that it has an inverse $\mod (p+q)$. This means that we need
$$x^3+y^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{(p+q)}$$

Now, if we pick $p=355$ and $q=113$, we get
$$p+q=468 = 7^3+5^3$$
In other words, the fraction $355/113$ has such a special property not because it is a convergent of $\pi$, but simply because the sum of numerator and denominator is a sum of two small cubes. We can do the same job with the fraction
$$\frac{203}{265} = \frac{5^3+78}{7^3-78}$$
nothing special with $\pi$.
As for $22/7$ we can find $$\frac{22}{7} = \frac{17^3+5^3}{12^3-5^3}$$
which is even more surprising. In my opinion, having three variables gives you a lot of freedom, so that yo can find such nice forms for any rational number.

EDIT: Just for fun, I looked up convergents of a completely different constant, namely $\gamma$: Euler-Mascheroni constant. One of its convergents is
$$\frac{71}{123}= \frac{3^3+470}{11^3-470}$$ Again, there is nothing special about this rational, simply you can find such a form for any number.

Comment: Great. A graphic for that beautiful $\frac{22}{7}$ would have the same symmetry as the one in the question if  $12$ was odd, or the four cubes even. Maybe your answer generalizes the question to how to build a continued fraction for a constant, that includes a particular approximation.

Comment: For $\gamma$, $3$ and $11$ would allow for two matching near-cubes, but $470=2·5·47$ has a factor too big for $3$ and $11$. The symmetry of the $\frac{355}{113}$ picture is due to the small factors in $12=2·2·3$.

Comment: Here's a [script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFUslOwzAQvfcrBilRbOK2qD0gVRhxQuLEB5SmcolDo2Zr7JgmiH9n7C4JCKm-eDzLmzfPc2DQAgcjahIcWBvQ0VNaaFmLdz2KZQJrUvHZjMGe3zMQjS7XTRULLfmzyJSkixHgyRGhghD27qW25SfZ6jwjgWcjfuwF4ENOqQsLdKkyM3KdlzE5RPOwjeYMwy5aNhrjy5V7JGUNDQMDaQHi2Moe5-Lwgjw_ZE0ayi62oZesNIEGOIe7vtAVQ8ghH2aZf7LMMevi67AfMdH8toIxNHjvKUynAxyhlKw1YArccOiG-GKjSEfhAfK0IJY7jWa_u-HQE1FVsogJ6ZibD8U66zFRZa3JTrY8E_kmFqAXDlMv71YnTa1Qp0KrFRb1DRJLHSnj_yCLqRsDh-h6pYSd7shyyLuDx7-yKEysA897S3BBvvzYofrx99EcW9Nzn23nFMjI2KtHlbgzVxHHPWJ4FbFfNnWWrKpxg0nwugvoDyypsQw=&lang=sage) using your method.

Comment: Some p, q combinations generate a lot of solutions, so my script only prints solutions with $|z|<\min(x, y)^2$, sorted (ascending) on $|z|$.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I got no solution for $\frac{25}{8}$ (a semiconvergent for $\pi$). Are there rationals that do not accept such a form or some issue in the implementation?